# Setting the path for cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Please guide me how do I run cleartool on my machine. I have searched on the internet, everwhere I am getting the path till bin to set in environment variables. But the issue with my setup is, i cannot see bin folder in clearcase.

Path for clearcase on my machine is

```
C: -> Program Files (x86) -> IBM -> RationalSDLCS -> clearcase -> RemoteClient
```

I can see rcleartool.bat and rcleartool.conf. When I tried to run bat file, it runs for few sec and getting closed after that.

Is there any other way to run cleartool without bin folder from machine?

One more path is `C: -> Program Files (x86) -> IBM -> SDPS -> bin`
I tried to set the path and run but not working. While running cleartool on command prompt, getting this error

```
cleartool' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: It worked! I set the path till cleartool only. I took some time. I had to start 3-4 times and finally it worked without setting the path till bin folder.

Comment: Great! I have also included this comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I tried to run bat file, it runs for few sec and getting closed after that.

Check your ClearCase version, and complete your question with the output of that command.
Make sure to execute the `rcleartool.bat` in an existing CMD session, instead of just doube-clicking it: that way, the output won't "disappear".

[`rcleartool`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728) is the remote CLI for CCRC (7.x and 8.0.x)

- See "[Getting Started with Remote Cleartool (rcleartool) - CCRC CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598728)"
- Make sure [your credentials are properly set](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21402372)

The [OP AIM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5001758/aim) confirms to be a [`PATH` issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695591/setting-the-path-for-cleartool#comment64150911_37695591):

> I set the path till `cleartool` only. I took some time.
>   I had to start 3-4 times and finally it worked without setting the path till `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Also, while you're at it, wait about 30 or so seconds to see if you get messages like this:

An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\configuration\1465933514149.log.

And then get the log file. I managed to break my JRE and classpath on one machine and CTE and rcleartool both failed.